# My firewall is blocking network connections from the docker container to outside

Tags: firewall, docker

For me this is a very standard setup, I had a ubuntu machine running docker and ufw as my firewall.

If my firewall is enable the docker instances is unable to connect to outside

```
$ docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
WARNING:  Docker detected local DNS server on resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4]
root@d300c5f17207:/# apt-get update
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is the ufw log showing the blocked connections from the docker container.

```
$ sudo tail /var/log/ufw.log
Jun 30 15:41:56 localhost kernel: [61609.503199] [UFW BLOCK] IN=testbr0 OUT=eth0 PHYSIN=veth8Rj8Nh MAC=fe:ff:ed:42:b0:01:0a:7c:42:7c:a6:72:08:00 SRC=172.16.42.2 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=14886 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60192 DPT=53 LEN=44 
Jun 30 15:42:01 localhost kernel: [61614.500867] [UFW BLOCK] IN=testbr0 OUT=eth0 PHYSIN=veth8Rj8Nh MAC=fe:ff:ed:42:b0:01:0a:7c:42:7c:a6:72:08:00 SRC=172.16.42.2 DST=8.8.4.4 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=16137 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44812 DPT=53 LEN=44 
Jun 30 15:42:06 localhost kernel: [61619.498516] [UFW BLOCK] IN=testbr0 OUT=eth0 PHYSIN=veth8Rj8Nh MAC=fe:ff:ed:42:b0:01:0a:7c:42:7c:a6:72:08:00 SRC=172.16.42.2 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=14887 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60192 DPT=53 LEN=44
```

I had try adding a rule using the ip.

```
$ sudo ufw allow in from 172.16.42.2
$ sudo ufw allow out from 172.16.42.2
```

And have no change is still blocked.

How can I esily allow all connections from the container to outside with a ufw rule?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Maybe this is due to the current version, but the current answer doesn't work on my system (Docker 0.7.2 with base Ubuntu image).*

**The solution is explained [here in the official Docker documentation](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/#ufw).**

For the lazy ones:

- edit `/etc/default/ufw` to change `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY`'s value to `"ACCEPT"`,
- reload with `[sudo] ufw reload`.

This ensures ufw forward your traffic to the Docker's bridged network (as of my current understanding of these things...).

Comment: This is no longer sufficient solution for more recent docker versions on ufw.

Answer (score 27):

This fixed it for me:

```
 ufw allow in on docker0
```

Comment: This worked for me too, while I think that the first step is also needed, as rchampourlier pointed out in his answer: setting the ufw DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY's value to "ACCEPT" .

Comment: Update: Sorry, my above comment is wrong. Only Franchus solution worked finally, of course together with rchampourliers solution (I tested first i a wrong environment)

Comment: I did an allow on `docker_gwbridge` which was what the ufw block lines in syslog were reporting. Since I only wanted postgres, it was:
```$ sudo ufw allow in on docker_gwbridge to any port 5432```
```
Rule added
Rule added (v6)
```

Answer (score 25):

Edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules` as follows:

In the ***filter** section, after the first block of required lines, add:

```
# docker rules to enable external network access from the container
# forward traffic accross the bridge 
-A ufw-before-forward -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -i testbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

At the end of the file, **after** the line that says `COMMIT`, add the following section:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.42.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

After saving the file, restart ufw with `sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable`

Comment: Thanks, Franchu, this did it. It would be nice if you would explain what all these settings finally mean (for me it's not really obvious).

Comment: Thanks, this helped. But keep in mind that this will not work for docker containers with an added subnet in docker-compose. If you definded the ip range e.g. 172.20.0.0/16, run ifconfig and add the new network interface (e.g. br-c0754ca0b709) in the *filter section.

Answer (score -1):

i use next filters for docker networks

```
#docker swarm
sudo ufw allow 2376/tcp
sudo ufw allow 2377/tcp
sudo ufw allow 7946/tcp
sudo ufw allow 7946/udp
sudo ufw allow 4789/udp
```