# Use local ssh port-forwarding from docker

Tags: docker, ssh

So, I'm calling a web-site (e.g https://ipinfo.io/ip) from dockerfile. Also I want to pass this traffic from `ssh local port-forward tunnel`.

so what I did,

1. create ssh tunnel

```
sudo ssh -N -L 0.0.0.0:443:ipinfo.io:443  my-username@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

2. add `ipinfo` in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 ipinfo.io
```

3. create a Dockerfile like

```
FROM alpine


RUN apk add curl 

RUN curl https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

so what happened `ipinfo.io` could resolve in loopback, but doesn't go through ssh tunnel.
How could I call `ipinfo.io` from docker, so that it goes through ssh tunnel?

P.S: I'm using macOS High Sierra

Comment: "but doesn't go through ssh tunnel" Exactly what happens when you try? Do you get error messages? What do they say?

Comment: it shows connection refuse

Comment: Container to host communication is prohibited due to security reasons. Instead create another container which will create the tunnel. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60430524/997162) on this topic.

Comment: you might be able to talk to host by using [host network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/) driver. Is it an option for you?

Comment: tried with host network. its not working for me. you could try and check, if you can work that out

Answer (score 4):

Here are the things I did to get it working:

1. Used IP address of `ipinfo.io` instead of using the hostname in the `ssh` command

```
sudo ssh -g -N -L 0.0.0.0:443:216.239.38.21:443 my-username@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

2. Used the below `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine


RUN apk add curl
RUN cat /etc/hosts

RUN curl -v https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

3. Performed build using the below command, where I mapped `ipinfo.io` to an IP my local machine (in this case the IP of virtual interface for docker):

```
docker build --add-host ipinfo.io:172.17.0.1 -t test:0.0.1 .
```

4. Sample output:

```
Step 3/4 : RUN cat /etc/hosts
 ---> Running in b7384b27c1a5
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.1      ipinfo.io
172.17.0.2      b7384b27c1a5
Removing intermediate container b7384b27c1a5
 ---> 2a8b062984b8
Step 4/4 : RUN curl -v https://ipinfo.io/ip
 ---> Running in 0fa2c413ab2c
Trying 172.17.0.1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ipinfo.io (172.17.0.1) port 443 (#0)
...
> GET /ip HTTP/2
> Host: ipinfo.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
> Accept: */*
>
...
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Fri, 20 Mar 2020 15:27:12 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 14
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< x-frame-options: DENY
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< via: 1.1 google
<
37.42.143.111
...
```

I think there might be a need to enable `GatewayPorts` in the `sshd_config` and restarting the `sshd` for this to work.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but Its not working for me. I've tried with enabling `GatewayPorts ` also.
another thing I'm using mac OS

Comment: did you remove the `127.0.0.1 ipinfo.io` from your `/etc/hosts`? Also could you run the command `ifconfig` and share them in your question just to be sure

Comment: I've removed from `/etc/hosts`. didn't work. also I'm using macOs High Sierra. whats your OS?

Comment: It's boot2docker tcl linux vm on windows, so what are you getting as output of the `docker build` command?

Comment: Thanks for the `-g` key. It allows to connect from other containers.