# Accessing SQL Server Container over an SSH tunnel

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a debian server that is hosting multiple services in docker containers. One of these services is a MS SQL Server, which I connect/ use on my local network and now am trying to access from a remote network.

I have enabled/configured openSSH on the host and have been able to connect to the system on my local environment. I've also been able to establish a connection on port 22 remotely after forwarding the ports on my router/firewall.

However when I try to access the SQL Server which is listening on another port the connection times out. I've forwarded the port in PuTTY as outlined in [this article](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse444/11wi/resources/tunneling-instructions.html) and in my SSMS I use 127.0.0.1,2021 (local listener). The remote port has also been forwarded on the router as demonstrated in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8f5zv9UUMI).

In desperation, I've also tried to use dynamic port forwarding (covered in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOmIqUs0fbY)) which also failed. I don't think that is what I'm going for but wanted to try everything before posting.

Even though I appear to be able to establish a remote SSH connection, I cannot establish a connection with the database. Is there something that needs to be configured in openSSH or docker/portainer? Please advise. Thanks!

edit: Is this the same problem I am having? [access host's ssh tunnel from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143689/access-hosts-ssh-tunnel-from-docker-container?rq=1)
As I read through this post it seems like it is having a connection issue from the other direction.

Comment: So when you `docker container ps -all` what port(s) does the SQL container publish? It's normal to publish `1433/tcp`, in which case your SSH tunnel could be established using something like `-L 2021:1433`

Comment: yeah exactly I'm using the the default `1433/tcp` and have established the tunnel as you mentioned using PuTTY

Comment: Perhaps Windows firewall is blocking connections to the tunnel port opened by PuTTY then. Have you gone to Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules and added a rule that allows incoming connections to the PuTTY executable?

Comment: One thing that's not clear from your question is whether you've successfully connected to the SQL instance from the Debian server or not. Consider using a tool like [mssql-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-ver15#linux-installation). First prove that the SQL Server instance is connectable from there, before trying to double-hop/tunnel through.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I just tried that and I am still timing out. Good thinking though

Comment: hey @gvee yes I can connect to the SQL instance no problem on my local network...is there a command I should run from CLI that will tell me something about the configuration?