# How could a docker container access a (mongo-db) service via an ssh tunnel on host

Tags: docker, ssh, tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a remote mongo-db instance that has restricted access to its local network. So, I create an ssh tunnel, which allows me to connect:

`ssh -L [port]:localhost:[hostport] [username]@[remote-ip]`

However, when I want to connect to the same mongo-db service from a docker container the connection times out.

I tried to [specify a bind address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120176/3665441) like so

`ssh -L 172.17.0.1:[port]:localhost:[host-port] [username]@[remote-ip]`

And connect to the remote mongo-db from a docker container at 172.17.0.1:[port], but without success. What's my mistake?

**Note:** I am looking for a solution that works on both Linux and Mac.

Comment: Just to be clear, to what address are you connecting in your container?

Comment: It's may be tricky getting a solution that works correctly in both instances, because the way a Docker container connects to your host is very different on Linux vs on MacOS (on MacOS, Docker is running in a Linux virtual machine). It might be easier to run the ssh proxy *in a container*.

Comment: I tried many things by now: but following https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120176/3665441 I connect to 172.17.0.1 from the container (alternatives I tried are localhost and the local ip of the machine I'm trying to access).

Comment: Thanks @larsks, are you suggesting that something like this should work? For example in a docker-compose setup: (1) create a container that tunnels into the server, and (2) from other containers access the tunneled service on the shared docker network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  sshproxy:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./id_rsa:/data/id_rsa
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        apk add --update openssh
        chmod 700 /data
        exec ssh -N -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no -i /data/id_rsa -g -L 3128:localhost:3128 alice@remotehost.example.com

  client:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        apk add --update curl
        while :; do
          curl -x http://sshproxy:3128 http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/New_York
          sleep 5
        done
```

Here I'm setting up an ssh tunnel that provides access to a remote
http proxy, and then in another container I'm accessing that proxy
over the ssh tunnel. This is pretty much exactly what you're looking to do with mongodb.

In a real environment, you would probably be using pre-built images, rather than installing packages on-the-fly as I've done in this example.

Comment: Great, many thanks! I have this working now by adding (building) an sshproxy container in docker-compose.yml and setting the host to "sshproxy" in pymongo.