# Access localhost from within docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, localhost, docker-network

I know there are a ton of similar issues, but none of them are working for me!

I'm running docker on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. All I want to do is access a Elasticsearch-Instance that i mapped onto Port `localhost:9208` via SSH-Tunnel, without switching the docker containers network mode to `host`.

Here is my minimal `docker-compose.yml` example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  curl_test:
    image: curlimages/curl
    command: "curl http://localhost:9208"
```

Output:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9208 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

I tried:

- Using the workaround using `"host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`
- Specifiying `extra_hosts`
- Mapping Port 9208 directly into the container

I know that this minimal example does not work. But all the fixes/changes proposed are not working. So I'm very glad for any suggestions for this problem.

Comment: Is your Elasticsearch also running as docker container and defined in docker-compose.yaml? If yes, all the services by default use bridge network. Have you tried to reach it with its service name defined in docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: No elasticsearch is running on a remote host outside any docker environment. But I'm mapping it to localhost with an ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it!

The solution contains two parts:

**1. Making hosts localhost accessible to docker container**

All it needed was

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

**2. More importantly: An SSH-Tunnel is not a normal localhost per se!**

This @felix-k's answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120176/18015508) made me realize I had to map the remote port to dockers docker0 interface. All it needed was an additional tunnel:

`ssh -N -L 172.17.0.1:9214:localhost:9200 user@remotehost`