# Docker. Send mail from host

Tags: ubuntu, docker, centos

I can send mails from host, using mail:

```
mail -s "Hooray" smb@example.com < /dev/null
```

But I want to send mails from docker container using host server. Docker says "port is already in use" when I try to map it to 25 port in run command:

```
run -ti -p 25:25 container
```

How I can achieve the goal?
Host is Centos, docker uses Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi. Did you find some solution?

Comment: @spiil hello, no, I gave up:) I managed to send emails directly from gmail smtp server

Comment: oh ok. thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score -1):

Using port forwarding with docker container you forward container's port to host. So you have port 25 already in use on host by mail server. Here you need to forward port from host to the container:

[Forward host port to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container)

The easiest way is to use `--net=host` option:

```
docker run --rm -it --net=host container mail -s "Hooray" smb@example.com < /dev/null
```

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do this without using --net=host? I am using several other containers in network also.

Answer (score -1):

You can't listen on the same port with multiple applications. So if there's already an application on the host listening on port 25, you can either stop that application, or configure your container to listen on a different host port, e.g.:

```
run -ti -p 2525:25 container
```

That causes the port to be mapped from the host port 2525 to the container port 25. If you don't need to receive mail from the container, you can remove this port mapping entirely, that will still allow you to send outbound messages.

If you don't know what is using port 25 on the host, you can look this up with a netstat command:

```
sudo netstat -lntp
```

Note that the sudo is required if you want to see the process that is listening on the port.

Comment: I want to send mails (don't want to recieve them at all) from container, so I don't need to map ports at all?

Comment: If you don't need to receive mail from the container, you can remove this port mapping entirely, that will still allow you to send outbound messages.