# scp from Docker container using internal IP address

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, ip-address

I have a Google Cloud instance with internal and external IP addresses:

```
hostname -I

10.......5 172......1
```

The first is the internal and the second is the external IP.

When I create a docker container and run the same command I get:

```
hostname -I

172......2
```

I want to scp data between two Google Cloud machines, and I want to make sure I'm not incurring any egress. How can I make sure the docker container uses the internal IP address in Google Cloud?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a port in the host from your docker, as per this [example](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/) but for an nginx. You can use [Host Networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) for your purpose.

This is explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container#26090569) already