# How to connect Flask app docker container to local mongoDB (not docker container)

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask

How to connect Flask app docker container to local mongoDB (not docker container) ? is it posibble? so hard to find tutorial to do this. I already read docker hub mongo but is not clear for me cause I'm new with docker. I try to create docker image mongo but is not connected to my local mongodb host cause running on container. please help me to understand.

this is my connection code I already using my host IP:

```
client = MongoClient("10.0.75.1", 27017)
db = client['RepositoryUIN']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward host port to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container)

Comment: Simply use the `ip` of the host machine to connect the DB.

Comment: thanks for response guys, @SaqibAhmed so am I need tell docker compose if I want to connect host ip ?

Comment: Nope. You don't need to do anything. In your flask app, simply hardcode the IP of your host machine (where mongoDB is running) and that's it.

Comment: Add the code in your question where you connected to DB in your app. @OttohHidayatullah

Comment: Does `10.0.75.1` has mongoDB running on it? Is this the IP of your docker host?

Comment: ok I try to rebuild images and run this take a little bit long time. can we skip a few step when we want rebuild our images?  @SaqibAhmed

Comment: What do you mean by steps?

Comment: yaa before you comment I'm using localhost. I check ipconfig and show me IP of dockerNAT, is that true? @SaqibAhmed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170024/discussion-between-saqib-ahmed-and-ottoh-hidayatullah).

Comment: you solved my problem thanks @SaqibAhmed