# Docker connect to server on host machine

Tags: docker, localhost, dockerfile, docker-container

Say on the host machine I have a server running on `localhost:4000`. How do I connect to that server from inside a Docker container?

This is a security risk in some cases, but in my case, this is running on my personal machine, so I can give the container all the privileges it needs to talk with the host machine.

For example in the Docker container, if I run:

```
RUN nc localhost 4000 | xargs echo
```

I don't think that's going to to be able to connect to the server running on the host, unless I take some extra steps.

Comment: I guess you will have to map the the port to the host: `docker run -d -p 4000:4000 --name example example`

Comment: I think this link might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container