# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 15672: Connection refused

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking, rabbitmq

I want to use jenkins to run our testcases but our application has set of docker container which will get initiated when i run npm run deploy:

problem: rabbitmq port is refused:localhost port 15672: Connection refused from inside the container while it is reachable outside the container.

following are the current setup details:

1. docker image from jenkins/jenkins:lts
2. using dockerfile that will build the dependencies for jenkins that 
   also has  curl docker(docker inside docker),
   docker build will build image tagged by
3. `docker run --name myjenkins -u root -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000
   -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v 
   /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock testSample`

   ```
   root@373d88dc52e5:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipelineDemo@script# curl http://localhost:15672
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 15672: Connection refused
   ```
4. but when I use `--net=host` in docker run command as follows:

   ```
   docker run --name myjenkins -u root -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000
   -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home 
   /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net =host testSample
   ```

Rabbitmq is responding and I can run all my test cases

but my project does not want me to use `--net=host` for security issues
is there any other way such that i can reach rabbitmq and run testcases?

Comment: There's many methods you can use, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container