# Flask in Docker container access localhost

Tags: python, docker, python-requests

On my localhost I have a Django application running on port 8000. 
A Docker compose sets up different containers, among them a Flask application with the config:

```
redirection-service:
  container_name: redirection-service
  build: 
    context: "..."
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  links:
    - redis
```

In the flask application I use a `requests` call to access an endpoint of the Django application on the localhost:

```
 backend_url = 'localhost:8000/...'
 requests.post(backend_url, data={}, allow_redirects=True, verify=False)
```

But I get the error

```
 requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /.../ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4d706f7588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Comment: When you connect to `localhost:8000` it's the same container network namespace.  Are both processes running in the same container?

Comment: As stated above, Django is running on the localhost and Flask inside a container

Comment: Django is running in localhost, and Flask is running in localhost, and they're different localhosts.

Comment: okay so how do I `request.post` from inside the container to the django app on the actual local host?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have in mind that different containers have different addresses. So localhost:8000 on flask has NO IDEA of the django running on the other container.
You need to use django's internal ip address or resolve the host name in another way

Comment: Django is not running in another container but on the local host

Comment: when you say localhost, is it the same container as the flask?

Comment: or django in your HOST COMPUTER and flask on the container?

Comment: django on the HOST COMPUTER and flask on the container

Comment: So thats it.... localhost on the container means "the container", you need to expose the host port to the container (you could use 8000)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container