# How to have docker container access remote database via host SSH connection?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a VM instance where I run the following Docker containers:

1. django
2. nginx
3. postgres
4. redis

My project is structured as thus:

```
project_root
     |
     |--- production.yml
     |--- .envs
     |       |
     |       |---.production
     |               |
     |               |---.postgres
     |
     |---... more Django apps
     |
     |--- compose
             |
             |---production
                   |
                   |---- django
                   |        |---- Dockerfile
                   |        |---- entrypoint
                   |        |---- start
                   |
                   |---- postgres
                            |---- Dockerfile
```

The `/compose/production/django/Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # git
  && apk add --no-cache git

RUN addgroup -S django \
    && adduser -S -G django django

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements/project.production.txt \
    && rm -rf /requirements

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint
RUN chown django /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/production/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start
RUN chown django /start

COPY . /app

RUN chown -R django /app

USER django

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

`/compose/production/django/entrypoint` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset


# N.B. If only .env files supported variable expansion...
export CELERY_BROKER_URL="${REDIS_URL}"

if [ -z "${POSTGRES_USER}" ]; then
    base_postgres_image_default_user='postgres'
    export POSTGRES_USER="${base_postgres_image_default_user}"
fi
export DATABASE_URL="postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}"

postgres_ready() {
python << END
import sys

import psycopg2

try:
    psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="${POSTGRES_DB}",
        user="${POSTGRES_USER}",
        password="${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}",
        host="${POSTGRES_HOST}",
        port="${POSTGRES_PORT}",
    )
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)

END
}
until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo 'Waiting for PostgreSQL to become available...'
  sleep 1
done
>&2 echo 'PostgreSQL is available'

exec "$@"
```

`/compose/production/django/start` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset


python /app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir=/app
```

The `/.envs/.production/.postgres` is as follows:

```
# PostgreSQL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=some_db
POSTGRES_USER=super_user_123
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=not_gonna_tell_you
```

`\production.yml`

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  production_caddy: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: project_production_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: project_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres

  caddy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/caddy/Dockerfile
    image: project_caddy
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - production_caddy:/root/.caddy
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.caddy
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2
```

Everything works when I run the Docker containers in the VM instance on the cloud.

### Objective

What happens is that I need to make the Django app access a remote database instead of the `postgres` container on the docker network. That remote database is outside the VM instance where these Docker containers are residing.

### What I tried

First, what I did was I set it up such that the VM instance (aka the docker host) can access this remote database via `localhost:15432`

#### Important note

This remote database is only accessible via reverse SSH hence, I need to use precisely only `localhost:15432` in the VM instance

This is 100% working. I can access the remote database using that address and port **from the VM instance aka the docker host**

Then I needed to have the django container access the same. This is where I run into issues.

I tried the following changes inside the `.postgres` file under `.envs`. They all failed

1. I tried to change `.postgres` such that I am using the IP of the docker host which I gather is typically `172.17.0.1`.
2. I also tried to use `localhost` directly.
3. I researched and read about setting up the network as host instead of bridge. But I cannot understand how to make changes, so I didn't do anything beyond reading up on docker docs about this.

There's a chance I need to have the `django` container be able to access BOTH the remote database and the `postgres` container.

But for now, I am happy just to be able to directly have the `django` container access the remote database without removing the postgres container totally.

How do I do so?

Comment: Don't you just need to forward your VM Host localhost:15432 to any other port in django container?
EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I don't quite understand it. How does that work?