# react native docker container using vs code to publish to android emulator on host OS

Tags: android, react-native, docker

I am trying to run a react native docker container on vs code. I am able to run my code. However, the container is not able to detect the android emulator running on my host machine.

`I followed along in this tutorial course:`

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers
&
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native

On running

> npx react-native run-android
> however, I get an error message that my emulator is not running. error
> Failed to install the app. Make sure you have an Android emulator
> running or a device connected. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more
> details. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug
> -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

My devcontainer.json:-

```
{
    "name": "React Native Android Container",
  
    // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
    "context": "..",
  
    // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
  
    "runArgs": [
        "--privileged", // give all capabilities to a container, in other words, the container can then do almost everything that the host can do
        "--net",
        "host", // forwarding all host machine ports
        "-v",
        "/dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb" // mount connected USB devices to a container
      ],
    
  
    "settings": {
      // This will ignore your local shell user setting for Linux since shells like zsh are typically
      // not in base container images. You can also update this to an specific shell to ensure VS Code
      // uses the right one for terminals and tasks. For example, /bin/bash (or /bin/ash for Alpine).
      "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": null
    },
  
    // Add the IDs of extensions you want to be installed when the container is created in the array below.
    "extensions": ["msjsdiag.vscode-react-native"]
  }
```

the runArgs "host" is supposed to forward all ports. I think I need a similar argument in the reverse direction?

Comment: running this on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: do you use an `adb` connection?

Comment: I am trying to connect to the android emulator started from android studio

Comment: I am not sure what adb is.. researching that now

Comment: the `adb` is Android Device Bridge, when you install Android Studio, you already have it. for checking adb, go to terminal and run `adb --version`. if you got the version so you have it. if not you should install it and when you see your emulator by `adb devices` command, then with `yarn android` you can install your app on your emulator.

Comment: I do have the adb and I am able to run the emulator on my local host machine. I am trying to connect to the emulator from the vs code container

Comment: did you get it to work I was about to try the same on my box if yes can you please share instruction on how you did it

Comment: not yet chandan.. if you get it to work post an answer here.. I will post as answer if I get it to work. Even  a bounty could not get me an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container this post may have a clue

Comment: Did you get more information about this?

Comment: @LautaroZarandon ... No , I gave up.

Comment: I am going to attempt to solve this mystery  one more time. If somebody was already able to figure out how this can be done, please enlighten this page.

Comment: Could you add your Dockerfile @ambassallo? I remember that someone adds a node.js server to expose some ports and stuff like that

Comment: Also, you're trying to create a local dev environment or a deploy configuration?

Comment: @JonathanSolorzano a local dev environment. A deploy config will not be useful. I am not sure if android devices support running containers. I will answer with dockerfile once I succeed.

Comment: @ambassallo, any luck?

Answer (score -1):

Check the permissions for `android/gradlew`. Can check the permissions using the below command:

`stat -c "%a %n" android/gradlew`

The permissions should be 755. If not change the permissions to 755 inside your app root folder.

`chmod 755 android/gradlew`

then run `react-native run-android`

Comment: what makes you think it is a gradlew permission problem?