# How do I connect to an external PSQL database from a Docker container on linux ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My telegram bot on aiogram 3.2 runs on a webhook (using nginx) inside a Docker container (I also use docker-compose). Here is the configuration of my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
   bot:
     build: .
     env_file: .env.development
     ports:
       - "82:3002"
     extra_hosts:
       - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
     restart: always
```

The PostgreSQL database is located on the same server as the docker container, locally (when testing on windows) everything works fine (in the .env file the host is specified as follows: **POSTGRES_HOST='host.docker.internal'**)
When trying to start a container on Linux Ubuntu, an error occurs: **connection to server at "172.17.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused** How to configure the container and database so that everything works as required?

I tried changing postgresql configuration files (allowing access for connections), setting up custom networks in docker-compose. None of the above helped.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31249112/5320906) answer your question? Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75649891/5320906)?