# Connecting a Dockerized Spring Boot app to a local MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I'm creating a spring boot project that needs to connect to a mysql database. I'm using Docker to automatizate the process of deploying.

1. I create the docker image with the nex command.

`docker build -t <projectname>`

This is the configuration of my application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/<db>
    
    spring.datasource.password= ....
    
    spring.datasource.username= ....
    
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

2. When I run the docker file image I get the next error: docker build -t

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

When I run the jar of the project, the project works properly and connect to the database, but with the docker image I can not connect to my local databas

Comment: Are both the java application and the database running in containers? Can you be more specific how you start them? If both are containers, localhost as the DB url is most likely wrong.

Comment: The DB is installed in my computer , it's not running in a container. I build the docker file image of m,y spring boot app and I run that image, but it doesn't connected to the DB.I think it is a network problem, but I am not sure. @TeemuRisikko

Comment: Ah, alright, then you need to do some tricks. The localhost of your host machine is not the same as the localhost for your container. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770902/forward-host-port-to-docker-container for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "localhost" you need to use "host.docker.internal"